# Preciso converter em PHP atual

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho um formulário antigo que gostaria de ajustar uma pagina com parâmetros atuais em PHP.
Segue código:

```
<?php include "login_senha.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $email_db = $linha['email'];
}
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($cont == 0){
echo"
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=cadastro02.php' />
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login nao existe')</script>
";
} else {
if($senha_db !=$senha){
echo"
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=cadastro02.php' />
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Senha nao corresponde')</script>
";
} else {
session_start();
$_SESSION['email_usuario'] = $email;

header("Location: segunda.php");
}
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dropdown");
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $record['item'] , '">' . $record['item'] .'"</option>';

}

mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Se não me engano hoje não é mais mysql e sim mysqli, correto?

Answer (score 0):

Funciona sim, deve haver algum outro erro no seu código...

Dá uma olhada no manual do php para cada função que não funcionar.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Testei este código abaixo usando xampp e base local e funcionou corretamente.

```html
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "base_teste");

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "base_teste");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $email_db = $linha['email'];
    echo '<br> email: ' . $email_db;
}
```

Comment: Oi amigo, funcionou, listou todos os e-mails do meu banco de dados, mas acaba que ele não faz o login, diz que usuário ão existe, sendo que está lá na listagem que ele mesmo mostra. Mesmo assim muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score -2):

SO mudar de "mysql_"   para "mysqli_", use CTRL + ESPAÇO que vai preencher de forma correto.
No mais é so testar...

Comment: Boa noite amigo, não deu certo. Eu consigo me conectar ao banco, fiz os testes aqui, mas ele não esta conseguindo ler os dados, fiz o que você me indicou, mas ele não consegue reconhecer o usuário cadastrado no banco. Dá a mensagem de como ele não existisse. :(